# jQuery Tabs - getting selected tab on page reload

Tags: jquery, tabs, selecteditem

I'm using the jQuery Tabs function from [jqueryfromdesigners](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs/), but only the first example works for me. That's the script-code I use:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$.noConflict();
        $(function () {
            var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
            tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

            $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
                tabContainers.hide();
                tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
                $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                return false;
            }).filter(':first').click();
        });
    </script>
```

And here's the demo-code for displaying the tabs:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <!-- tabs -->
  <ul class="tabNavigation">
    <li><a href="#first">Send a message</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second">Share a file</a></li>
    <li><a href="#third">Arrange a meetup</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- tab containers -->
  <div id="first">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="third">
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have already changed the code for my use. In the tab-content-divs are now displayed informations which I grab via php. This content has many links in it that reloads the page when clicked.

How can I achieve that when the user clicks on a link in #tab2 the page reloads and displays the last selected #tab2? Now it always shows #tab0...

I would appreciate any hint on this!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a hash tag with the url and on page load you can access the hash using `window.location.hash` . Based on the hash tag , you can make the corresponding tab selected

So in your case a simple woraround would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     tabContainers.hide();
     tabContainers.filter(window.location.hash).show();
     $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
     return false;

});
```

Comment: Hi Sethunath!

Thx for you quick reply!

So I have implemented your code directly under my script-code and tried to access the site like this:

http://www.xyz.com/site.html?#second

But still the first tab is shown...

Comment: You should put the code inside $(document).ready(function(){
 after .filter(':first').click(); . That might help

Comment: Thx again Sethunath...but I don't get it...please take a look at answer #3, where I've explained what I've tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

You can use with [cookie](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#option-cookie)

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30 } });
```

Comment: Hi coder!

Thx for your reply, too!

I'm hoping to get this to work without implementing another plugin/script, like the one you've linked to. But if nothing else will work I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Thx again for your reply!

I tried several variations, but nothing worked...

If I use the following code, where I implemented the first code from you below my tab-script in a separate call nothing happens:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$.noConflict();
        $(function () {
            var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
            tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

            $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
                tabContainers.hide();
                tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
                $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                return false;
            }).filter(':first').click();
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
     tabContainers.hide();
     tabContainers.filter(window.location.hash).show();
     $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
     return false;

});
</script>
```

I choose a tab (for example tab#3), click on a link, the site reloads I still get displayed tab#1...

2nd version I tried:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$.noConflict();
        $(function () {
            var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
            tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

            $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
                tabContainers.hide();
                tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
                $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                return false;
            }).filter(':first').click();
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
     tabContainers.hide();
     tabContainers.filter(window.location.hash).show();
     $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
     return false;

});
</script>
```

Same as before, the site reloads and shows tab#1...

With the third version the tabs are all hidden, I first need to click on a tab to get it displayed...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$.noConflict();
        $(function () {
            var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
            tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

            $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
                tabContainers.hide();
                tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
                $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                return false;
            }).filter(':first').click();


$(document).ready(function(){
     tabContainers.hide();
     tabContainers.filter(window.location.hash).show();
     $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
     return false;
});

});
</script>
```

On click and site-reload the tabs are hidden again...

It would be great if you could take another look at this. I don't know what to do to get this running...

Cheers!

Comment: Ok, now I got it! I placed the hash-tag wrong inside the url, so now it works...but there's still one little problem left...when the user visits the site first no hash-tag is given. How can I say "if hash-tag is empty then choose tab#1"? also the css-state is not active, whether on page-reload or first-visit, only if I click on a tab the css-class "selected" is active...